# jQuery transformable plugin - just rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So there's this sweet jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/transformable that does skew, scale, and rotate. I'm making a visual editor with objects that you can resize/move/rotate, and all I need is the rotate part. Is there a stripped-down version of this with just the rotate handle? I've tried extracting that part, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn the other features off when setting transformable up. Like this:

```
$('#yourElement').transformable({scalable:false, skewable:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

***Did you know...?***

This plugin can become touch compatible with the addition of jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Works on Android give it a shot:    http://jsfiddle.net/vbSMy/2475/

```
CDN: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
```